# How can I download a file using a simple HttpClient example?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm new with Java and HttpClient, and I'm trying to do a simple download from a Dropbox file but I just get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.<init>(AbstractHttpClient.java:187)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.<init>(DefaultHttpClient.java:146)
    at downlaodtest.DownlaodTest.main(DownlaodTest.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 3 more
Java Result: 1
```

Why is the exception thrown?

```
public class DownlaodTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://dl.dropbox.com/s/ex4clsfmiu142dy/test.zip");
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
    System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    if (entity != null) {
      InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
      try {
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(instream);
        String filePath = "C:/@Victor";
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath)));
        int inByte;
        while ((inByte = bis.read()) != -1 ) {
          bos.write(inByte);
        }
        bis.close();
        bos.close();
      } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw ex;
      } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        httpget.abort();
        throw ex;
      } finally {
        instream.close();
      }
      httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "not working". That's an unacceptable description of a problem, unless you aren't a programmer.

Comment: The trick is to read the exception. `ClassNotFoundException` means it cannot find a class. `org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory` is the class it cannot find. Because it's in a different .jar file that the apache commons httpclient depends on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works fine on my machine if I change the file path to a valid path and add all of the libraries it needs to the classpath.

```
String filePath = "d:\\test.zip";
```

Libraries:

```
commons-codec-1.6.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
fluent-hc-4.2.3.jar
httpclient-4.2.3.jar
httpclient-cache-4.2.3.jar
httpcore-4.2.2.jar
httpmime-4.2.3.jar
```

Comment: What error are you getting? (And you should pick a path that's valid on your machine.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add the lines below to save your file.

```
response.addHeader(“Content-Disposition”, “attachment;filename=\”" + file.getName() + “\”");
response.addHeader(“Content-Transfer-Encoding”, “binary”);`
response.setContentType(“application/octet-stream”);`
response.setContentLength((int) file.length());`
response.getOutputStream().write(buffer);`
response.getOutputStream().flush();`
```

Comment: then the problem might by your system not able to connect with the given site or you are not authorized to do.

Comment: Let me rephrase: His code works without change. Only the file path is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you're new to Java, you must learn about managing Java dependencies.

Either you download binary distribution with dependencies and copy them all to your project and add to Eclipse, or you learn to use **maven**.

For example, you add the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.0-alpha4</version>
</dependency>
```

and maven is doing everything else for you (downloading all dependencies with their dependencies).