# SQLiteHelper producing NullPointerException for FileReader

Tags: android, xml, sqlite, csv

Okay I'm working with SQLiteHelper class to load a CSV File from a URL resource and then load into my SQLite DB. However I'm getting a LogCat error that doesn't stop the application, but also doesn't load the data into my application.

This is my first experience with SQLite so could any provide any advice where am I going wrong? I've provided a LogCat printout for reference.

**MYSQliteHelper.java**

```
public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    String filename;
    FileReader file; 

    //Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    //Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "CatalogueDB";

    //Catalogue records table name
    private static final String TABLE_RECORDS = "records";

    //Catalogue records column names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_GROUP = "category";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_IMAGE = "image";
    private static final String KEY_DESC = "description";
    private static final String KEY_ADDR = "address";
    private static final String KEY_TELEPHONE = "telephone";
    private static final String KEY_URL = "url";
    private static final String KEY_LAT = "latitude";
    private static final String KEY_LNG = "longitude";

    //Array of Strings used to create database columns
    private static final String[] COLUMNS = {KEY_ID, KEY_GROUP, KEY_NAME, KEY_IMAGE, KEY_DESC, KEY_ADDR, 
                                             KEY_TELEPHONE, KEY_URL, KEY_LAT, KEY_LNG};

    public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //SQL statement to create records (map markers) table
        String CREATE_RECORDS_TABLE ="CREATE TABLE records (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
        "category TEXT, " + 
        "name TEXT, " +
        "image TEXT, " +
        "description TEXT, " +
        "address TEXT, " +
        "telephone TEXT, " +
        "url TEXT, " +
        "latitude TEXT, " +
        "longitude TEXT" + ")";

        //Create records (map markers) table
        db.execSQL(CREATE_RECORDS_TABLE);

        new CSVFileDownloader().execute(); // RETURN CSV FILE FROM URL/SERVER

        //LOAD CSV FILE
        try {
            file = new FileReader(filename);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("FILE: " + file);
        System.out.println("FILE DOWNLOADED: " + filename);

        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(file);
        String line = "";
        //String tableName = TABLE_RECORDS;
        //String[] columns = COLUMNS;
        String str1 = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_RECORDS + " (" + COLUMNS + ") values (";
        String str2 = ");";

        db.beginTransaction();
        try {

            while ((line= buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str1);
                String[] str = line.split(","); // CSV split
                sb.append("'" + str[0] + "',");
                sb.append(str[1] + "', ");
                sb.append(str[2] + "', ");
                sb.append(str[3] + "', ");
                sb.append(str[4] + "', ");
                sb.append(str[5] + "', ");
                sb.append(str[6] + "', ");
                sb.append(str[7] + "', ");
                sb.append(str[8] + "', ");
                sb.append(str[9] + "', ");
                sb.append(str2);
                db.execSQL(sb.toString()); //ADD CSV RECORD INTO DATABASE
            }
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
            db.endTransaction();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And then my `AsynchTask` method that gets my CSV file from web resource:

```
        private class CSVFileDownloader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                new AuthScope(null, -1),
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password"));

            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();

            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.cardigan.cc/app/locations.csv");

            HttpResponse response = null;

            try {
                response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
                filename = response.toString(); //LOAD RESPONSE(the file) INTO FILENAME

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            String result = "";
            return null;                
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }
```

N.B. That private class is within `MySQLiteHelper.java`

And finally the LogCat printout.

```
02-22 18:21:31.360: W/dalvikvm(18407): threadid=5: spin on suspend #1 threadid=1 (pcf=0)
02-22 18:21:31.610: W/dalvikvm(18407): threadid=5: spin on suspend resolved in 1255 msec 
02-22 18:21:33.490: W/ActivityThread(18407): ClassLoader.loadClass: The class loader returned by Thread.getContextClassLoader() may fail for processes that host multiple applications. You should explicitly specify a context class loader. For example: Thread.setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
02-22 18:21:34.290: W/System.err(18407): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-22 18:21:34.410: W/System.err(18407):    at java.io.File.fixSlashes(File.java:185)
02-22 18:21:34.410: W/System.err(18407):    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:134)
02-22 18:21:34.410: W/System.err(18407):    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:105)
02-22 18:21:34.410: W/System.err(18407):    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:66)
02-22 18:21:34.410: W/System.err(18407):    at uk.ac.aber.dwd.util.CeredigionTourism.MySQLiteHelper.onCreate(MySQLiteHelper.java:85)
02-22 18:21:34.410: W/System.err(18407):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
02-22 18:21:34.410: W/System.err(18407):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)
02-22 18:21:34.410: W/System.err(18407):    at uk.ac.aber.dwd.util.CeredigionTourism.MySQLiteHelper.getAllMapMarkers(MySQLiteHelper.java:202)
02-22 18:21:34.410: W/System.err(18407):    at uk.ac.aber.dwd.CeredigionTourism.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.java:40)
02-22 18:21:34.410: W/System.err(18407):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5240)
02-22 18:21:34.410: W/System.err(18407):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
02-22 18:21:34.410: W/System.err(18407):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
02-22 18:21:34.410: W/System.err(18407):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
02-22 18:21:34.410: W/System.err(18407):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-22 18:21:34.410: W/System.err(18407):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
02-22 18:21:34.410: W/System.err(18407):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-22 18:21:34.410: W/System.err(18407):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-22 18:21:34.410: W/System.err(18407):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5048)
02-22 18:21:34.410: W/System.err(18407):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-22 18:21:34.410: W/System.err(18407):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-22 18:21:34.410: W/System.err(18407):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
02-22 18:21:34.410: W/System.err(18407):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:675)
02-22 18:21:34.410: W/System.err(18407):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting a NullPointerException because you're trying to open a file with a null filename:

```
file = new FileReader(filename);
```

It seems like you're trying to initialize filename asynchronously, so I'm guessing that what's happening is that you're getting to the `new FileReader(filename)` code before getting to `filename = response.toString();`

The correct solution would be to only start your `AsyncTask` in the `onCreate()` function, and do the rest after the `AsyncTask` has completed (i.e. in its `onPostExecute()` function).

Comment: but I have done that because I've done `new CSVFileDownloader().execute()` before even dealing with the `file` variable.

Comment: As the name of the function in CSVFileDownloader implies, the code there runs in the background. This means that once you call that `execute()` function, both the AsyncTask's code and the `onCreate()` code will run concurrently. Obviously, the `onCreate()` is losing the race. As I wrote in my answer above, you want to alter your code to have it wait for the CSVFileDownloader to complete its work.

Comment: I've now put the `FileReader` code in the `onPostExecute()` function. But I'm getting a `FileNotFoundException`. How do I convert my `filename` String in the above code into the actual file that has download. Also, do you think that code successfully downloads the .CSV resource?

Comment: You are getting an HttpResponse object. Invoking its `toString()` method is definitely **not** the way to go. I strongly recommend you [search](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=defaulthttpclient+download+file+example) for material on the subject of saving downloaded content to a file. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539453/how-can-i-download-a-file-using-a-simple-httpclient-example) could help.